# Font color in a table doesn't inherit from parent div

Tags: html, css, inheritance

For example I have a div with font color set to purple, some text within the div inherits the color, but some are not, e.g. in a table. (Save below code as `test.html` and open in the browser for testing)

```
<div style="color: purple;">
  <p>Some text</p> <!-- text here is purple -->
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Table cell 1</td> <!-- text here is NOT purple -->
      <td>Table cell 2</td> <!-- text here is NOT purple -->
    </tr>
  </table>
  Another text <!-- text here is purple -->
</div>
```

If I replace the div with body, they DO inherit.

```
<body style="color: purple;">
  <p>Some text</p> <!-- text here is purple -->
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Table cell 1</td> <!-- text here is purple -->
      <td>Table cell 2</td> <!-- text here is purple -->
    </tr>
  </table>
  Another text <!-- text here is purple -->
</body>
```

I'd like to know that:

1. Why and how do they NOT inherit the style from the parent container?
2. Is there an alternative workaround to make the content elements inherit the font color, as if they inherit from the body?

Comment: In which browser(s)? I see purple text in both cases.

Comment: You probably have a reset somewhere. The color should normally inherit.

Comment: @panther I tested them on IE, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari (on Windows 7 SP1), and all of them give the same result...

Comment: In most browsers, you can right click on the element on the page and click "Inspect Element" This will bring up a window that shows you what style is being applied, and what styles it is overriding.

Comment: So you do not have any other css, and is not using any frameworks or plugins..? can you replicate this in a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something..?

Comment: Add fiddle of problem code, or link to your site. It this piece of code, there is no fault.

Comment: @TJ see here:
1. https://d5862db8b4f37332908cfa4a91d1ea381613ee6e.googledrive.com/host/0B508-K_C3xoXRHh6dloxbjlaU3M/test1.html
2. https://d5862db8b4f37332908cfa4a91d1ea381613ee6e.googledrive.com/host/0B508-K_C3xoXRHh6dloxbjlaU3M/test2.html

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This 'issue' is caused by the fact that you haven't declared a doctype, causing the browser to run in Quircks mode.

One result of this is what you see happening here: The table element is getting a `color: -webkit-text;` style which overrides the inheritance from the parent div.

Adding:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

at the top of your document will cause the browser to render the page you'd want it to.

Comment: In my case, it was a PHP warning that was inserted before the DOCTYPE…

Comment: Can't believe Hacker News lacks this declaration

Comment: How did I not know this until 2018. Thank you.

Comment: Adding doctype breaks some other "quirks" on which the design was relying originally (yup, that's very legacy code here…). Is there a way to disable the "Quirks mode" for selected elements? =)

Comment: @pilat I'm not sure how to disable all "quirks mode" features for an element, but if it's just the color of the table, you can use `table{color: inherit}`. You may also find the following useful: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.1/normalize.css

Answer (score 2):

1. > Why and how do they NOT inherit the style from the parent container?

   It seems that browser specific styles are being applied to `<table>` element.
2. > Is there an alternative workaround to make the content elements inherit the font color, as if they inherit from the body?

   To override this, simply add the following to your css

   ```
   table{
    color:inherit;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Your css style is overridden by the table css from another style sheet you have.

[image: color is set by webkit]

Add this to your css file

```
#purple, table{
    color: purple;
}
```

or let the table inherit the css of your div

```
table {
   color: inherit; 
}
```

and this to your html

```
<div style="color: purple;">
  <p>Some text</p> <!-- text here is purple -->
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Table cell 1</td> <!-- text here is NOT purple -->
      <td>Table cell 2</td> <!-- text here is NOT purple -->
    </tr>
  </table>
  Another text <!-- text here is purple -->
</div>
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/36aZ8/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

add css to table also

```
     <style> 
         #divc,table{
        color: purple;
        } 

        </style>

    <div id="divc">
      <p>Some text</p> <!-- text here is purple -->
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Table cell 1</td> <!-- text here is NOT purple -->
          <td>Table cell 2</td> <!-- text here is NOT purple -->
        </tr>
      </table>

  Another text <!-- text here is purple -->
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T7JBB/